# combine all 3 digit numbers in a row into 1 single number in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix of 3 digit numbers, for example

```
   102   106   100   100   100   100   100

   106   102   100   100   100   100   100

   106   101   120   106   109   119   108

   104   115   107   106   109   119   108
```

I would like to combine each row into a single number, like so

```
102106100100100100100

106102100100100100100

106101120106109
```

...etc. I would really appreciate any feedback. Thank you :)

Comment: Please show us how you “have a matrix”; is it a variable? A file? Something a user typed in?

Comment: it's a cell array of strings coverted into a matrix of those numbers above and made the same length

Answer (score 2):

I assume the input is a numeric 2D array.

If you want the result in string form (2D char array where each row represents a number):

```
result = num2str(A, '%i'); %// or change format specifier if the numers are not naturals
```

If you want the result in numeric form (column vector of numbers):

```
result = str2num(num2str(A, '%i'));
```

Comment: Quick query, is there any way of transferring the resulting column vector back into a matrix, where each row of the column vector is now split up into elements of 3 digit numbers as in the original question? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @FrancesBeresford Use `reshape(str2num(reshape(num2str(result).',3,[]).'),[size(A,2) size(A,1)]).'`. But note some of the recovered entries may be wrong because of `float`'s finite precision